# ASP MVC Model validation not working in view

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Below is the model validation I have set up in my ASP MVC 3 site. I want to enforce a characer limit and prevent non-alphanumeric characters from being entered.

However.. none of the validation here is working. Each time I enter either `$#@` or go over the character limit the form still posts back to the controller.

Only 2nd/3rd time using regex so not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Model**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ChannelMetaData))]
public partial class Channel1
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; } 
}
class ChannelMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Channel Code required")]
    [DisplayName("Channel Code")]
    [StringLength(1)]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Channel Code")]
    public string ChannelCode { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Channel Short Description")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Channel Short Description required")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Channel Short Description")]
    public string ChannelDescription { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Channel Long Description")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Channel Long Description required")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Channel Long Description")]
    public string ChannelLongDescription { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using System.Collections.Specialized
@model IEnumerable<Monet.Models.Channel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditChannels";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>EditChannels</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm("EditChannels", "ZipCodeTerritory", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Channel Code</th>
            <th>Channel Description</th>
            <th>Channel Long Description</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Id)
                    <td>
                        <center>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.ChannelCode, new { style="width:10px;" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.ChannelCode)                            
                        </center>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.ChannelDescription, new { maxlength = 10 })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.ChannelDescription)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.ChannelLongDescription, new { maxlength = 30 })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.ChannelLongDescription)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.Status, new SelectList(
                                                                        new List<Object>
                                                                            {
                                                                                new {value = "A", text = "A"},
                                                                                new {value = "I", text = "I"}
                                                                            }, "value", "text", item.Status))
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            <input type="submit" name="Save"/>
            @Html.Raw("&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;")
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateChannel", "ZipCodeTerritory")
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditChannels(IEnumerable<Channel> channels)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (Channel item in channels)
            {
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            return View(channels);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**EDIT**

Per answer below I've added the following scripts to the bottom of the `Layout.cshtml` file.

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-unobtrustive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included all the `js` files?

Comment: i'm 90% sure it's because you are using a foreach loop

Comment: @Jonesy - what does the foreach loop have to do w/validation?

Comment: You can't have more than one field with the same id or name, by using a foreach you're just telling it to write out the same field with a different value.

Comment: Validation occurs during model binding in your post action, and you haven't included that in your question.  I'm guessing you're using FormsCollection rather than your actual model?

Comment: Just added the controller to the post. No matter what values I put in there it passes the `ModelState.IsValid` line every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your partial class that you have the metadata assigned to is called Channel1

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ChannelMetaData))]
public partial class Channel1
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; } 
}
```

But the model you are binding against is Channel

```
public ActionResult EditChannels(IEnumerable<**Channel**> channels)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're loading the js files in the correct order?
I had this problem in the past and solved changed the load order of js files.
Try to load js file in this order:

- jquery library (load this file inside head tag)

put the following files at end of html (or cshtml) before /body tag

- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax
- jquery.validate
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive
- jquery-ui-{version}.js
- jquery.blockUI.js

Comment: I'm not using any jquery, javascript, or ajax on the page.

Comment: But the validation helper does

Comment: Hm.. maybe that's the problem :)

Comment: Still now working. Added to the Layout and the view itself. Updated the post w/the new info.

Answer (score 2):

use a for loop, so you can directly relate your properties back to the model:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
     <tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Id)
        <td>
            <center>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].ChannelCode, new { style="width:10px;" })                  
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].ChannelCode)                            
             </center>
        </td>

     //etc..
}
```

when you use `@Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Id)` you are losing the 'connection' (someone please correct my terminology) back to the model

Comment: This is the way to go.

Comment: This solved a separate problem I was having posting the entire list back to the controller, however I still am not getting the validation messages. If I enter non-alphanumeric or a string larger than the character limit the form will do a post back.

Comment: are you checking `ModelState.IsValid` on your post?

Comment: Yep. This is the first line in the controller: `if (ModelState.IsValid)`

Comment: It shouldn't be posting back to the controller, however, if I'm failing any of these validations

Answer (score 1):

This wound up being the result of a simple typo in this section

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ChannelMetaData))]
public partial class Channel1
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; } 
}
```

The partial class name needs to be `Channel` instead of `Channel1`

Comment: I guess we both noticed it at the same time.